# No rule to make target .o, why?

Tags: c++, makefile

This is the first makefile of my life! I have a project in which I have the *src* folder (in which I keep my .cpp files), an *include* folder (in which I keep my .hpp files) and a *build* folder in which I would like to store my object files.

```
 # define the C compiler to use
CCXX = g++ -std=c++11

# define any compile-time flags
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
INCLUDES = -I./include

#define the directory for src files
SRCDIR = ./src/

#define the directive for object files
OBJDIR = ./build/

# define the C source files
SRCS = action.cpp conditionedBT.cpp control_flow_node.cpp execution_node.cpp main.cpp

# define the C object files 
OBJS = $(OBJDIR)$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

# define the executable file 
MAIN = out

.PHONY: depend 

all: $(MAIN)
    @echo Program compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CCXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: ($SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CCXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c -o $@ $<
#.c.o:
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
#clean:
#   $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(addprefix $(SRCDIR),$(SRCS))
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

Given the above, I get the following error when I try to execute make:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `build/action.o', needed by `out'.  Stop.
```

Comment: `.c` is not the same as `.cpp`.

Comment: `CC`, `CFLAGS` is for C, so it won't be picked up by default rules either. Better use `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems with your `Makefile`.

**1)** You are using the `.c` extension when your files use `.cpp`.

**2)** Your substitution directive `OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)` doesn't take into account the subdirectories of your sources and objects.

**3)** Your general rule to make objects is not getting invoked for those reasons but also because you don't specify the subdirectory of the sources.

Because of that `make` is making up its own rules to compile your object and ignoring the rule you made.

Also I would recommend using the correct implicit variables for `C++` which would make the implicit rules work better.

They are detailed here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

So I would recommend something more like this:

```
# define the C compiler to use
CXX = g++ 

# define any compile-time flags
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -Wall

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
CPPFLAGS = -I./include

#define the directive for object files
OBJDIR = ./build
SRCDIR = ./src

# define the C source files
SRCS = $(SRCDIR)/action.cpp $(SRCDIR)/main.cpp

# define the C object files 
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

# define the executable file 
MAIN = out

.PHONY: depend 

all: $(MAIN)
    @echo Program compiled

$(MAIN): $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) $(OBJS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    @echo "Compiling: " $@
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)/*.o *~ $(MAIN)

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```